# swagger editor error with put request

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

In the following swagger documentation, I got a parameter definition error.

```
  /store/{Filepath}:
    put:
      summary: Store file to the archive
      description: ""
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: Filepath
          type: string
          description: Filename
          required: true
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: File to be uploaded
          required: true
          type: file
      responses:
        "201":
          description: File sucessfully stored
```

This generate the `Not a valid parameter definition` error and point on the line above `- in: body` I can't see what's wrong do any of you find what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you intend to define a `formData` parameter?  For example:

```
    - in: formData
      name: body
      description: File to be uploaded
      required: true
      type: file
```

That should eliminate the error, but I'm not sure it's what you intended.

If you really intended to define a `body` parameter, it needs a `schema` property:

```
    - in: body
      name: body
      description: File to be uploaded
      required: true
      schema:
        type: object
```